# PHP File Uploading

Tags: php, windows, easyphp

I'm getting index not found errors on a processing page for $_FILES. So far as I know my code is technically correct (at least the two other people who've looked at it can't find any errors either).

So first, the function that is called that displays the form with the file upload:

```
function portfolioEditor($p) {
    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"" . siteurl . "/manage/update.php\">";
    echo '<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="grid4 first" value="' . $p['name'] . '" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="posttype" id="posttype" class="grid4" value="' . $p['posttype'] . '" />';
    echo "\n<br />\n";
    echo '<textarea name="content" id="content" class="grid8 first">' . $p['content'] . '</textarea>';
    echo "\n<br />\n";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />';
    echo '<input name="file" value="' . $p['image'] . '" id="file" type="file" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="true" id="fileup" name="fileup" />';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

(take it as a given that the page with the form calls portfolioEditor($p) with details for $p filled in, or blanks for a new item.)

This is the update page (without the database insert yet)

```
$p = $_POST;

$p['url'] = str_replace(" ", "-", $p['name']);

foreach ($p as $k => $v) {
    $p[$k] = addslashes($v);
    //echo $v;
}

// FILE UPLOAD IF NEEDED
if(isset($p['fileup']) && $p['fileup'] == "true") {
    $loc = sitepath . "/files";
    $loc = $loc . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $loc);
}
```

I have no idea why this isn't working, every resource I've seen on writing your own upload script uses almost the exact same code.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set the `value` of a input of type `file`. Due to security issues, browsers should not allow this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add this to your form:

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

So your form tag becomes:

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" enctype='multipart/form-data' action=\"" . siteurl . "/manage/update.php\">";
```

Answer (score 3):

add as `form` tag attribute `encytype="multipart/form-data"`

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"" . siteurl . "/manage/update.php\" encytype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
```

Comment: You copied my answer? Really? Your original post was `add as form tag attribute encytype="multipart/form-data"`... Just as an FYI, it's better to up-vote than copying answers.

Comment: Sorry, but cdburgess got there first.

Comment: @cdburgess: That is your small thought you shown here. What do you think, If I'm correct every time means I copied your answer? humm, I seen you downvoted does not matter that's shows your small thoughts. I prey to god that `GET WELL SOON`

Answer (score 1):

When you are submitting a file, the form should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` defined such as

```
echo "<form 
method=\"post\"
enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"
action=\"" . siteurl . "/manage/update.php\">";
```

Comment: Your enctype will cause an exception. The "'s need to be escaped using \.